# AudioRecord - Invalid audio buffer size

Tags: android, audiorecord, audioformat

I have a problem with below lines when using `AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_8BIT` as AudioFormat. When using `AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT` these work fine.

```
bufferSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(sampleRate, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_8BIT); 
audio = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.CAMCORDER, sampleRate, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_8BIT, bufferSize);
```

logcat:

```
03-26 10:03:49.643: E/AndroidRuntime(19949): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-26 10:03:49.643: E/AndroidRuntime(19949): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid audio buffer size.
03-26 10:03:49.643: E/AndroidRuntime(19949):    at android.media.AudioRecord.audioBuffSizeCheck(AudioRecord.java:340)
03-26 10:03:49.643: E/AndroidRuntime(19949):    at android.media.AudioRecord.<init>(AudioRecord.java:237)
03-26 10:03:49.643: E/AndroidRuntime(19949):    at com.kris.test.SoundMeter.runForCamMic(SoundMeter.java:57)
03-26 10:03:49.643: E/AndroidRuntime(19949):    at com.kris.test.VolumeCalc.run(VolumeCalc.java:89)
03-26 10:03:49.643: E/AndroidRuntime(19949):    at com.kris.test.StateChecker.micCalibration(StateChecker.java:159)
03-26 10:03:49.643: E/AndroidRuntime(19949):    at com.kris.test.Settings$3.onClick(Settings.java:354)
03-26 10:03:49.643: E/AndroidRuntime(19949):    at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:167)
03-26 10:03:49.643: E/AndroidRuntime(19949):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-26 10:03:49.643: E/AndroidRuntime(19949):    at   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-26 10:03:49.643: E/AndroidRuntime(19949):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4921)
03-26 10:03:49.643: E/AndroidRuntime(19949):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-26 10:03:49.643: E/AndroidRuntime(19949):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-26 10:03:49.643: E/AndroidRuntime(19949):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1027)
03-26 10:03:49.643: E/AndroidRuntime(19949):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:794)
03-26 10:03:49.643: E/AndroidRuntime(19949):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: What is the value of `bufferSize`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize` does not support `PCM_8BIT` (see the [AudioRecord source code)](https://www.codeaurora.org/gitweb/quic/la/?p=platform/frameworks/base.git;a=blob;f=media/java/android/media/AudioRecord.java;h=1be73276e63ac1b0d7af974f507e5f1624daf418;hb=refs/heads/jb_mr1#l477), and will return `ERROR_BAD_VALUE` (-2) if you pass a `PCM_8BIT` format to it.

One solution would be to switch to using `PCM_16BIT` encoding. Another possibility (which I haven't verified whether it works) is to ask for a minimum buffer size based on `PCM_16BIT` and divide the returned size by 2 when constructing the `AudioRecord` instance.