# Cannot initialize a valid AudioRecord

Tags: android, android-audiorecord

I am trying to instantiate an `AudioRecord` in order to monitor the audio in real time, but it fails even though I try multiple different configurations.

**I've tried restarting my phone multiple times**, and I have

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
```

in my manifest (in the `<manifest>` tag, not in the `<application>` tag).

The solutions I've found for this problem have been to make sure the permission is correct and is in the right place (**check**), to make sure to call `release()` on all `AudioRecord` instances (**check**), to restart the phone (**check**) and to use a method of finding a valid combination of sample rate, audio format and channel configuration (**check**).

I've tried this on a Samsung Galaxy S5 running Android 4.4.2 and a Motorola Moto G running Android 4.4.4 by the way.

Here's my code for trying to find a valid `AudioRecord`:

```
public AudioRecord findAudioRecord() {
    int[] mSampleRates = new int[] { 44100, 11025, 22050, 16000, 8000 };
    short [] aformats = new short[] { AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_8BIT };
    short [] chConfigs = new short[] { AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_STEREO };


    for (int rate : mSampleRates) {
        for (short audioFormat : aformats) {
            for (short channelConfig : chConfigs) {
                try {
                    Log.d("SoundMeter", "Attempting rate " + rate + "Hz, bits: " + audioFormat + ", channel: " + channelConfig);
                    int bufferSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(rate, channelConfig, audioFormat);

                    if (bufferSize != AudioRecord.ERROR_BAD_VALUE) {
                        Log.d("SoundMeter", "Buffer size OK");

                        // Try to instantiate
                        AudioRecord recorder = new AudioRecord(android.media.MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC, rate, channelConfig, audioFormat, java.lang.Math.max(bufferSize,1024*800));

                        if( recorder.getState() == AudioRecord.STATE_INITIALIZED ){
                            Log.d("SoundMeter", "Success: AudioRecord initialized!");
                            return recorder;
                        }
                        else {
                            Log.d("SoundMeter", "Failed: AudioRecord not initialized");

                            // Important! Release recorder
                            recorder.release();
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("SoundMeter", "Exception on sample rate " + rate + "\n   ", e);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    Log.println(Log.ASSERT, "SoundMeter", "No valid audio record configuration found!");

    return null;
}
```

And here's the logcat from running the above method:

```
05-20 11:42:34.146 8326-8326/com.my.app D/SoundMeter: Attempting rate 44100Hz, bits: 2, channel: 16
05-20 11:42:34.156 8326-8326/com.my.app D/SoundMeter: Buffer size OK
05-20 11:42:34.196 8326-8326/com.my.app E/AudioRecord: AudioFlinger could not create record track, status: -12
05-20 11:42:34.196 8326-8326/com.my.app E/AudioRecord-JNI: Error creating AudioRecord instance: initialization check failed.
05-20 11:42:34.196 8326-8326/com.my.app E/android.media.AudioRecord: Error code -20 when initializing native AudioRecord object.
05-20 11:42:34.196 8326-8326/com.my.app D/SoundMeter: Failed: AudioRecord not initialized
05-20 11:42:34.196 8326-8326/com.my.app D/SoundMeter: Attempting rate 44100Hz, bits: 2, channel: 12
05-20 11:42:34.196 8326-8326/com.my.app D/SoundMeter: Buffer size OK
05-20 11:42:34.196 8326-8326/com.my.app E/AudioRecord: AudioFlinger could not create record track, status: -12
05-20 11:42:34.206 8326-8326/com.my.app E/AudioRecord-JNI: Error creating AudioRecord instance: initialization check failed.
05-20 11:42:34.206 8326-8326/com.my.app E/android.media.AudioRecord: Error code -20 when initializing native AudioRecord object.
05-20 11:42:34.206 8326-8326/com.my.app D/SoundMeter: Failed: AudioRecord not initialized
05-20 11:42:34.206 8326-8326/com.my.app D/SoundMeter: Attempting rate 44100Hz, bits: 3, channel: 16
05-20 11:42:34.206 8326-8326/com.my.app E/android.media.AudioRecord: getMinBufferSize(): Invalid audio format.
05-20 11:42:34.206 8326-8326/com.my.app D/SoundMeter: Attempting rate 44100Hz, bits: 3, channel: 12
05-20 11:42:34.206 8326-8326/com.my.app E/android.media.AudioRecord: getMinBufferSize(): Invalid audio format.
05-20 11:42:34.206 8326-8326/com.my.app D/SoundMeter: Attempting rate 11025Hz, bits: 2, channel: 16
05-20 11:42:34.206 8326-8326/com.my.app D/SoundMeter: Buffer size OK
05-20 11:42:34.206 8326-8326/com.my.app E/AudioRecord: AudioFlinger could not create record track, status: -12
05-20 11:42:34.206 8326-8326/com.my.app E/AudioRecord-JNI: Error creating AudioRecord instance: initialization check failed.
05-20 11:42:34.206 8326-8326/com.my.app E/android.media.AudioRecord: Error code -20 when initializing native AudioRecord object.
05-20 11:42:34.206 8326-8326/com.my.app D/SoundMeter: Failed: AudioRecord not initialized
05-20 11:42:34.206 8326-8326/com.my.app D/SoundMeter: Attempting rate 11025Hz, bits: 2, channel: 12
05-20 11:42:34.206 8326-8326/com.my.app D/SoundMeter: Buffer size OK
05-20 11:42:34.216 8326-8326/com.my.app E/AudioRecord: AudioFlinger could not create record track, status: -12
05-20 11:42:34.216 8326-8326/com.my.app E/AudioRecord-JNI: Error creating AudioRecord instance: initialization check failed.
05-20 11:42:34.216 8326-8326/com.my.app E/android.media.AudioRecord: Error code -20 when initializing native AudioRecord object.
05-20 11:42:34.216 8326-8326/com.my.app D/SoundMeter: Failed: AudioRecord not initialized
05-20 11:42:34.216 8326-8326/com.my.app D/SoundMeter: Attempting rate 11025Hz, bits: 3, channel: 16
05-20 11:42:34.216 8326-8326/com.my.app E/android.media.AudioRecord: getMinBufferSize(): Invalid audio format.
05-20 11:42:34.216 8326-8326/com.my.app D/SoundMeter: Attempting rate 11025Hz, bits: 3, channel: 12
05-20 11:42:34.216 8326-8326/com.my.app E/android.media.AudioRecord: getMinBufferSize(): Invalid audio format.
05-20 11:42:34.216 8326-8326/com.my.app D/SoundMeter: Attempting rate 22050Hz, bits: 2, channel: 16
05-20 11:42:34.216 8326-8326/com.my.app D/SoundMeter: Buffer size OK
05-20 11:42:34.216 8326-8326/com.my.app E/AudioRecord: AudioFlinger could not create record track, status: -12
05-20 11:42:34.216 8326-8326/com.my.app E/AudioRecord-JNI: Error creating AudioRecord instance: initialization check failed.
05-20 11:42:34.216 8326-8326/com.my.app E/android.media.AudioRecord: Error code -20 when initializing native AudioRecord object.
05-20 11:42:34.216 8326-8326/com.my.app D/SoundMeter: Failed: AudioRecord not initialized
05-20 11:42:34.216 8326-8326/com.my.app D/SoundMeter: Attempting rate 22050Hz, bits: 2, channel: 12
05-20 11:42:34.226 8326-8326/com.my.app D/SoundMeter: Buffer size OK
05-20 11:42:34.226 8326-8326/com.my.app E/AudioRecord: AudioFlinger could not create record track, status: -12
05-20 11:42:34.226 8326-8326/com.my.app E/AudioRecord-JNI: Error creating AudioRecord instance: initialization check failed.
05-20 11:42:34.226 8326-8326/com.my.app E/android.media.AudioRecord: Error code -20 when initializing native AudioRecord object.
05-20 11:42:34.226 8326-8326/com.my.app D/SoundMeter: Failed: AudioRecord not initialized
05-20 11:42:34.226 8326-8326/com.my.app D/SoundMeter: Attempting rate 22050Hz, bits: 3, channel: 16
05-20 11:42:34.226 8326-8326/com.my.app E/android.media.AudioRecord: getMinBufferSize(): Invalid audio format.
05-20 11:42:34.226 8326-8326/com.my.app D/SoundMeter: Attempting rate 22050Hz, bits: 3, channel: 12
05-20 11:42:34.226 8326-8326/com.my.app E/android.media.AudioRecord: getMinBufferSize(): Invalid audio format.
05-20 11:42:34.226 8326-8326/com.my.app D/SoundMeter: Attempting rate 16000Hz, bits: 2, channel: 16
05-20 11:42:34.226 8326-8326/com.my.app D/SoundMeter: Buffer size OK
05-20 11:42:34.226 8326-8326/com.my.app E/AudioRecord: AudioFlinger could not create record track, status: -12
05-20 11:42:34.236 8326-8326/com.my.app E/AudioRecord-JNI: Error creating AudioRecord instance: initialization check failed.
05-20 11:42:34.236 8326-8326/com.my.app E/android.media.AudioRecord: Error code -20 when initializing native AudioRecord object.
05-20 11:42:34.236 8326-8326/com.my.app D/SoundMeter: Failed: AudioRecord not initialized
05-20 11:42:34.236 8326-8326/com.my.app D/SoundMeter: Attempting rate 16000Hz, bits: 2, channel: 12
05-20 11:42:34.236 8326-8326/com.my.app D/SoundMeter: Buffer size OK
05-20 11:42:34.236 8326-8326/com.my.app E/AudioRecord: AudioFlinger could not create record track, status: -12
05-20 11:42:34.236 8326-8326/com.my.app E/AudioRecord-JNI: Error creating AudioRecord instance: initialization check failed.
05-20 11:42:34.236 8326-8326/com.my.app E/android.media.AudioRecord: Error code -20 when initializing native AudioRecord object.
05-20 11:42:34.236 8326-8326/com.my.app D/SoundMeter: Failed: AudioRecord not initialized
05-20 11:42:34.236 8326-8326/com.my.app D/SoundMeter: Attempting rate 16000Hz, bits: 3, channel: 16
05-20 11:42:34.236 8326-8326/com.my.app E/android.media.AudioRecord: getMinBufferSize(): Invalid audio format.
05-20 11:42:34.236 8326-8326/com.my.app D/SoundMeter: Attempting rate 16000Hz, bits: 3, channel: 12
05-20 11:42:34.236 8326-8326/com.my.app E/android.media.AudioRecord: getMinBufferSize(): Invalid audio format.
05-20 11:42:34.236 8326-8326/com.my.app D/SoundMeter: Attempting rate 8000Hz, bits: 2, channel: 16
05-20 11:42:34.236 8326-8326/com.my.app D/SoundMeter: Buffer size OK
05-20 11:42:34.246 8326-8326/com.my.app E/AudioRecord: AudioFlinger could not create record track, status: -12
05-20 11:42:34.246 8326-8326/com.my.app E/AudioRecord-JNI: Error creating AudioRecord instance: initialization check failed.
05-20 11:42:34.246 8326-8326/com.my.app E/android.media.AudioRecord: Error code -20 when initializing native AudioRecord object.
05-20 11:42:34.246 8326-8326/com.my.app D/SoundMeter: Failed: AudioRecord not initialized
05-20 11:42:34.246 8326-8326/com.my.app D/SoundMeter: Attempting rate 8000Hz, bits: 2, channel: 12
05-20 11:42:34.246 8326-8326/com.my.app D/SoundMeter: Buffer size OK
05-20 11:42:34.246 8326-8326/com.my.app E/AudioRecord: AudioFlinger could not create record track, status: -12
05-20 11:42:34.256 8326-8326/com.my.app E/AudioRecord-JNI: Error creating AudioRecord instance: initialization check failed.
05-20 11:42:34.256 8326-8326/com.my.app E/android.media.AudioRecord: Error code -20 when initializing native AudioRecord object.
05-20 11:42:34.256 8326-8326/com.my.app D/SoundMeter: Failed: AudioRecord not initialized
05-20 11:42:34.256 8326-8326/com.my.app D/SoundMeter: Attempting rate 8000Hz, bits: 3, channel: 16
05-20 11:42:34.256 8326-8326/com.my.app E/android.media.AudioRecord: getMinBufferSize(): Invalid audio format.
05-20 11:42:34.256 8326-8326/com.my.app D/SoundMeter: Attempting rate 8000Hz, bits: 3, channel: 12
05-20 11:42:34.256 8326-8326/com.my.app E/android.media.AudioRecord: getMinBufferSize(): Invalid audio format.
05-20 11:42:34.256 8326-8326/com.my.app A/SoundMeter: No valid audio record configuration found!
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this post for reference, It says `AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize` does not support `PCM_8BIT`

[AudioRecord - Invalid audio buffer size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15633452/audiorecord-invalid-audio-buffer-size)

Hope this may help you.

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately that only solves half the problem - now I don't get the `Invalid audio format` errors, but the rest of the errors are just the same as before...

Comment: Try doing clean project and rebuild app, Maybe it will work after it. To support this ans please refer the link.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4843739/audiorecord-object-not-initializing